# How to select the specific row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select the rows where the revenue is `NaN`. So, row 7 and row 43 should be selected. I tried the code (`In[117]`) shown in the screenshot but it doesn't work for me.

[image]

Comment: Please post sample data and code in text format. - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: If you can make the requested edit, we can get this question reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html):

```
NaN_table[NaN_table['Revenue'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! May I know when should I include the `loc` and when not?

Comment: From the documentation,`.loc[]` is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array. Please see this page [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

```
NaN_table[NaN_table.Revenue.isna()]
```